# Google Chrome Home Page

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome as my Web browser.

It should show the recently opened pages in a larger size (like Boxes). But it never shows for me.

Most Visited and Recently Closed are the 2 options that I have towards my left bottom of my window.

What should I do?

Comment: which version? tried clicking Most Visited and Recently Closed options?

Comment: it always shows for me when I open a new tab. I haven;t looked how to make it my home page but would be interested to see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could just be that the boxes are minimised. This is what happened to me.

Just click on the little ‘reveal’ triangle/arrow thing next to ‘Most Visited’ and it should open back up again.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

1. Click on the "Most Visited" or "Recently Closed" text at the bottom of your browser's start page.
2. In the pop-up menu that appears, click the bottom-most item by the same name.
3. Voilà! The larger-sized boxes will appear.

   (Chrome should remember your settings the next time you open it.)

Answer (score 0):

Under the menu (wrench icon) - if you go to "Options", and then the "Basic" tab, is the "Open the Home Page" button selected at the top?  If not, that might be the problem.